# iOS - change volume for each AVAssetTrack

Tags: ios, swift, avmutablecomposition

I have some audio files that I need to insert in an `AVMutableComposition`. Each audio have a different volume. To accomplish that I created an `AVMutableTrackComposition` and an `AVAssetTrack` for each audio file. So I change the volume for every track using an instance of `AVMutableAudioMix`.

```
let composition = AVMutableComposition()
var trackMixArray = NSMutableArray()

for audio in layer{
   let trackAudio:AVMutableCompositionTrack = composition.addMutableTrackWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID())

   let file = project.stringByAppendingPathComponent(audio.name)
   let soundAsset = AVURLAsset(URL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: file), options: option as [NSObject : AnyObject])
   let sounds = soundAsset.tracksWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)
   var sound:AVAssetTrack = sounds[0] as! AVAssetTrack
   let duration:CMTime = sound.timeRange.duration

   let audioTimeRange:CMTimeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(kCMTimeZero, duration)
   let start:CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(audio.start.toDouble()!, 600)
   let stop:CMTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(audio.stop.toDouble()!, 600)

   let trackMix = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: trackAudio)
   trackMix.setVolume(audio.volume, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
   trackMixArray.addObject(trackMix)

   trackAudio.insertTimeRange(audioTimeRange, ofTrack: sound, atTime: start, error: nil)
 }

let audioMix = AVMutableAudioMix()
audioMix.inputParameters = trackMixArray as [AnyObject]
```

Using a single `AVMutableCompositionTrack` with more `AVAssetTrack` associated to it doesn't allow me to change the volume for each track.

```
 let trackMix = AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters(track: sound)
 trackMix.setVolume(audio.volume, atTime: kCMTimeZero)
 trackMixArray.addObject(trackMix)
```

It's possible to change the volume directly from the `AVAssetTrack`?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't allow me to change the volume for each track"? What do you mean by "change the volume directly"? Explain clearly what you are trying to _do_.

Comment: I can change the volume for each AVMutableCompositionTrack but not for each AVAssetTrack. To do that I have to assign each AVAssetTrack to a  AVMutableCompositionTrack and change the volume from  AVMutableCompositionTrack.

Comment: My goal is to use a single AVMutableCompositionTrack cause using to much of it slow the declaration of an AVPlayerItem

Comment: I still don't see the problem. You have explained beautifully how to set the preferred volume of an asset track, by dropping down to the mutable composition track subclass where it is mutable. So just do that. A mutable composition track _is_ an asset track; you can use the former wherever you can use the latter.

Comment: Class. Subclass. Do you see?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Can anyone suggest me how can we set volume for each Video clips?

Answer (score 1):

```
    AVMutableComposition *collageComposition = [[AVMutableComposition alloc]init];
        ...
        Some Magic
        ...
    NSArray *tracksToDuck = [collageComposition tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];
            audioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
            NSMutableArray *trackMixArray = [NSMutableArray array];
            for (int i = 0; i < [tracksToDuck count]; i++) {
                AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *trackMix = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:[tracksToDuck objectAtIndex:i]];
                        [trackMix setVolume:volume atTime:kCMTimeZero];
                [trackMixArray addObject:trackMix];
            }
            audioMix.inputParameters = trackMixArray;

    ... 
    AVAssetExportSession Magic
    ...
    generalExporter = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWith...
    generalExporter.audioMix = audioMix;
```

This should help you to change volume in each track, just change it to swift.

EDIT:
each `AVMutableCompositionTrack` have segments, each segment have startTime and duration, you can use `AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters` to change volume for each `CMTimeRange`

```
 - (void)setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:(float)startVolume
                         toEndVolume:(float)endVolume
                           timeRange:(CMTimeRange)timeRange
```

Comment: this change the volume for each AVMutableCompositionTrack and not for each AVAssetTrack